# Click to hide each div and show another div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery. Trying to hide the first div and show second div. When I again click on 2nd div, it will show me the first div.

Here is my code.

```js
$(".c1").on('click', function() {
  $(".one").fadeIn();
  $(".two").fadeOut();
});
$(".c2").on('click', function() {
  $(".two").fadeIn();
  $(".one").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.right {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.ab-container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.container {
  padding: 30px 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ab-container one">
    <div class="ab-head">
      <h1>This is div 1 <a href="" class="right c1"> Click to see div 2</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ab-content">
      <p>In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a filler text or greeking commonly used to demonstrate </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ab-container two">
    <div class="ab-head ">
      <h1>This is div 2 <a href="" class="right c2"> Click to see div 1</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ab-content">
      <p>Replacing meaningful content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

- You have your `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` calls inverted.
- You need to `prevent` the `a` link behavior.
- Pass as callback your `fadeIn` call.

## Look at this code snippet with those fixes

*I've added a `hide` class to show how the DIVs appear and disappear.*

```js
$(".c1").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".one").fadeOut(function() {
    $(".two").fadeIn();
  });  
});

$(".c2").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".two").fadeOut(function() {
    $(".one").fadeIn();
  });  
});
```

```css
.right {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.ab-container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.container {
  padding: 30px 60px;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ab-container one">
    <div class="ab-head">
      <h1>This is div 1 <a href="" class="right c1"> Click to see div 2</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ab-content">
      <p>In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a filler text or greeking commonly used to demonstrate </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ab-container two hide">
    <div class="ab-head ">
      <h1>This is div 2 <a href="" class="right c2"> Click to see div 1</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ab-content">
      <p>Replacing meaningful content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See? now is working your logic!

Answer (score 1):

First, it will work better if you use spans instead of links

The nyou have the order of fadein/fadeout confused:

```js
$(".c1").on('click', function() {
  $(".two").fadeIn();
  $(".one").fadeOut();
});
$(".c2").on('click', function() {
  $(".one").fadeIn();
  $(".two").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.right {
   font-size: 20px;
   float: right;
   margin-right: 50px;
}
.ab-container {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
.container {
   padding: 30px 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ab-container one">
     <div class="ab-head">
        <h1>This is div 1 <span class="right c1"> Click to see div 2</span></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="ab-content">
        <p>In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a filler text or greeking commonly used to demonstrate </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ab-container two">
     <div class="ab-head ">
        <h1>This is div 2 <span class="right c2"> Click to see div 1</span></h1>
     </div>
     <div class="ab-content">
        <p>Replacing meaningful content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working you only need to remove the `href=""` from your `<a>` tag. However, here is my way of doing it if you like to take a look. And the edited version of the HTML

```js
$('.c1').click(function () {
  $('.one').fadeIn();
  $('.two').fadeOut();
})

$('.c2').click(function () {
  $('.two').fadeIn();
  $('.one').fadeOut();
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ab-container one">
     <div class="ab-head">
        <h1>This is div 1 <a class="right c1"> Click to see div 2</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="ab-content">
        <p>In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a filler text or greeking commonly used to demonstrate </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ab-container two">
     <div class="ab-head ">
        <h1>This is div 2 <a class="right c2"> Click to see div 1</a></h1>
     </div>
     <div class="ab-content">
        <p>Replacing meaningful content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```